# execute batch command in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to run a batch command in c# code.

I tried this code but it only pops up cmd but I want it to pop up cmd and displays "Hello World".

```
Process.Start("cmd", "echo Hello World");
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/K echo Hello World");
```

(Note the "/K")

based on [this reference for cmd.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

Comment: Cool website! Thanks for the link.